Ocaml extlib-1.4 installation
I've tried to install extlib-1.4 but got an error(i'm noob)
I typed ocaml install.ml and got:
File "bitSet.ml", line 23, characters 40-53:
23 | let bcreate : int -> intern = Obj.magic String.create
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Alert deprecated: Stdlib.String.create
Use Bytes.create/BytesLabels.create instead.
File "bitSet.ml", line 28, characters 64-75:
28 | let fast_fill : intern -> int -> int -> int -> unit = Obj.magic String.fill
                                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^
Alert deprecated: Stdlib.String.fill
Use Bytes.fill/BytesLabels.fill instead.
ocamlc -c dynArray.ml
ocamlc -c extHashtbl.ml
File "extHashtbl.ml", line 1:
Error: The implementation extHashtbl.ml
       does not match the interface extHashtbl.cmi:  ... In module Hashtbl:
       Values do not match:
         val create : ?random:bool -> int -> ('a, 'b) t
       is not included in
         val create : int -> ('a, 'b) t
       File "extHashtbl.mli", line 76, characters 1-31: Expected declaration
       File "hashtbl.mli", lines 31-32, characters 0-30: Actual declaration
Exit Code 2 - Stopped

I don't understand why ocaml pays attention to String.create and String.fill
I don't know why it doesn't implement extHashtbl.ml
I need that exact version of findlib for RLDev, but it looks like it's too old for ocaml(or this version of ocaml just doesn't fit)

Version 1.4 of extlib is quite out of date. The opam page for extlib shows that version 1.5.2 (the oldest version listed) dates from November 2013 or almost 11 years ago.
The standard libraries that extlib seeks to extend have changed since then, and you're almost certainly not using an OCaml compiler and standard library from that long ago (I hope not!). The warnings and errors you're seeing almost certainly derive from those discrepancies.
The ideal way to install OCaml packages is the OCaml package manager, opam.
